# Accessing the API logger in Flask-Restful's resources

Tags: python, rest, flask

I'm currently using flask-restful (http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/index.html) to deploy resources as endpoints and I'm wondering if there's a way to access the API logger from within then resources classes. I've skimmed through the docs and couldn't find the appropriate answer.

Basically I want to do that :

```
from flask_restful import Resource 

class SomeEndpoint(Resource):

    def get(self):

        try:

            ... something throws an exception

        except SomeException as se:

            ... send custom message to API logger         <----- Here!

        return response
```

What I though of doing was passing the logger from the API through the constructor of the Resource like that :

```
App = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(App)
api.add_resource(SomeEndpoint, '/', resource_class_kwargs={'logger': App.logger})
```

Is this the most appropriate way to access the logger inside flask-restful resource endpoints ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define [constructor](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/intermediate-usage.html#passing-constructor-parameters-into-resources) of Resource. Here an example:

```
import logging


class SomeEndpoint(Resource):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.logger = kwargs.get('logger')

    def get(self):
        # self.logger - 'logger' from resource_class_kwargs
        return self.logger.name  

api.add_resource(SomeEndpoint, '/', resource_class_kwargs={
    # any logger here...
    'logger': logging.getLogger('my_custom_logger')
})
```

Open your endpoint. You will see `my_custom_logger`. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I forgot to add my constructor in the original question but yeah that's what I'm doing. I just wanted to know if that was the best way to do it. It looks like it is.

Answer (score 18):

I know the answer has been chosen already, but there is a slightly different approach that also works.

First, import

`from flask import current_app as app`

in the resource file, and when calling the logger, do:

`app.logger.info("This is an info message")`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it is cleaner (do not share loggers across by yourself!) and simpler

Comment: @MartinSeeler sorry but I not agree with you. The question about `API logger + constructor of Resource` but not about `app logger`. All depends on requirements and details. I mean very unusual cases (specific `logger` for specific `resources` with custom `handlers` and level settings etc). By the way, `from flask import current_app` works only when `app context` is available.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Yes, you're right. That was not the question. Maybe I was too biased, because it was the cleanest and simplest solution for my case.

Comment: This is slick and clean, didn't test yet though.

Answer (score 0):

Setting debug=False temporarily fixes the problem.

But I dont really know what is the issue when debug is set to True